# How to find all coastal cities globally using the Entity framework?

Tags: geography, entity

It seems to be an easy task as all the related functions `GeoNearest` and `EntityList["City"]` are close at hands.

However, for example, if we use

```
GeoNearest["City", Entity["Ocean", "PacificOcean"], 30]
```

to retrieve some cities, as the query size could be huge, we will always get such error:
[image]

So, what would be the sensible/feasible approach to get a global list of coastal cities using the `Entity` framework?

Comment: I think that the first thing I would try if I was on a machine with Mathematica installed would be to get a list of cities with elevations less than some threshold, say 50m, and see what pops out.  I suspect selecting cities on a simple criterion like the value of a property will be a lot less computationally burdensome than the `GeoNearest[ ... theOcean]` approach.

Comment: Well, I just tried my previous suggestion in MMA online, got a list of ~28,000 cities!

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark it would also be possible to filter those after the fact, since 28K is much easier to work with

Comment: Yes, that's rather the way I was suggesting OP goes.

Answer (score 4):

As a workaround you can use the ocean polygon instead, e.g.:

```
GeoNearest[
    "City",
    Entity["Ocean","PacificOcean"]["Polygon"],
    30
]
```

> {Entity["City", {"Avera", "Tubuai", "FrenchPolynesia"}],
> Entity["City", {"Niusuatia", "Tuamasaga", "Samoa"}],
> Entity["City", {"Uturoa", "IlesSousLeVent", "FrenchPolynesia"}],
> Entity["City", {"Fakahima", "TuamotuGambier", "FrenchPolynesia"}],
> Entity["City", {"Salesatele", "Atua", "Samoa"}],
> Entity["City", {"Sapulu", "FaAsaleleaga", "Samoa"}],
> Entity["City", {"Samamea", "VaAOFonoti", "Samoa"}],
> Entity["City", {"Tafagamanu", "AAna", "Samoa"}],
> Entity["City", {"Vailoa", "Tuamasaga", "Samoa"}],
> Entity["City", {"Anaa", "TuamotuGambier", "FrenchPolynesia"}],
> Entity["City", {"Ofu", "Manua", "AmericanSamoa"}],
> Entity["City", {"Papeete", "IlesDuVent", "FrenchPolynesia"}],
> Entity["City", {"SalelavaluTai", "FaAsaleleaga", "Samoa"}],
> Entity["City", {"Paepaeala", "AigaILeTai", "Samoa"}],
> Entity["City", {"Afega", "Tuamasaga", "Samoa"}],
> Entity["City", {"Faleu", "AigaILeTai", "Samoa"}],
> Entity["City", {"Taahuaia", "Tubuai", "FrenchPolynesia"}],
> Entity["City", {"Asaga", "FaAsaleleaga", "Samoa"}],
> Entity["City", {"Tufutafoe", "Vaisigano", "Samoa"}],
> Entity["City", {"ApolimaIsland", "AigaILeTai", "Samoa"}],
> Entity["City", {"SiumuUta", "Tuamasaga", "Samoa"}],
> Entity["City", {"Faleseela", "AAna", "Samoa"}],
> Entity["City", {"Maupiti", "IlesSousLeVent", "FrenchPolynesia"}],
> Entity["City", {"Mauga", "GagaEmauga", "Samoa"}],
> Entity["City", {"Apia", "Tuamasaga", "Samoa"}],
> Entity["City", {"IslandViewPiosBeach", "BayOfPlenty", "NewZealand"}],
> Entity["City", {"Mutis", "Choco", "Colombia"}],
> Entity["City", {"Kavieng", "NewIreland", "PapuaNewGuinea"}],
> Entity["City", {"Pimentel", "Lambayeque", "Peru"}],
> Entity["City", {"Palestina", "Guayas", "Ecuador"}]}

Since you're interested in the coastline, the following might be better:

```
GeoNearest[
    "City",
    Line @@ Entity["Ocean","PacificOcean"]["Polygon"],
    30
]
```

> {Entity["City", {"IslandViewPiosBeach", "BayOfPlenty", "NewZealand"}],
> Entity["City", {"Mutis", "Choco", "Colombia"}],
> Entity["City", {"Kavieng", "NewIreland", "PapuaNewGuinea"}],
> Entity["City", {"Pimentel", "Lambayeque", "Peru"}],
> Entity["City", {"Palestina", "Guayas", "Ecuador"}],
> Entity["City", {"Cabra", "Panama", "Panama"}],
> Entity["City", {"Aberpura", "Papua", "Indonesia"}],
> Entity["City", {"AlvaroObregon", "Chiapas", "Mexico"}],
> Entity["City", {"Acacoyagua", "Chiapas", "Mexico"}],
> Entity["City", {"Santiago", "Veraguas", "Panama"}],
> Entity["City", {"BuenosAires", "Puntarenas", "CostaRica"}],
> Entity["City", {"Courtenay", "BritishColumbia", "Canada"}],
> Entity["City", {"Salem", "Oregon", "UnitedStates"}],
> Entity["City", {"Damascus", "Oregon", "UnitedStates"}],
> Entity["City", {"Roxana", "Limon", "CostaRica"}],
> Entity["City", {"LosChiles", "Alajuela", "CostaRica"}],
> Entity["City", {"Gizo", "Western", "SolomonIslands"}],
> Entity["City", {"Barranco", "BocasDelToro", "Panama"}],
> Entity["City", {"Limon", "Limon", "CostaRica"}],
> Entity["City", {"Karuizawa", "Nagano", "Japan"}],
> Entity["City", {"Cabanas", "Zacapa", "Guatemala"}],
> Entity["City", {"LeGrand", "California", "UnitedStates"}],
> Entity["City", {"Suwa", "Nagano", "Japan"}],
> Entity["City", {"WhiteRock", "BritishColumbia", "Canada"}],
> Entity["City", {"Ambato", "Tungurahua", "Ecuador"}],
> Entity["City", {"Buritica", "Antioquia", "Colombia"}],
> Entity["City", {"Oluta", "Veracruz", "Mexico"}],
> Entity["City", {"Abejorral", "Antioquia", "Colombia"}],
> Entity["City", {"Wasco", "Oregon", "UnitedStates"}],
> Entity["City", {"BarraDeSantaAna", "Tabasco", "Mexico"}]}

Since the [`Polygon`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Polygon) and [`Line`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Line) versions work, it might be worthwhile asking support why the plain [`Entity`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Entity) version doesn't work